# sudo apt-get update doesn't connect to sources

Tags: linux

when I want to run this command `sudo apt-get update` in linux mint14 I get stuck in wating for header file.
and I see this in terminal  `0% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting f`

Comment: you should ask this question in http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
inxi -r
```

In terminal and check the repositories which are printed for you in the output.
They may be incorrect; if that is the case modify

> /etc/apt/sources.list

file into a working repository you know.